# Generate Self-sign certificate from existing CA

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl

I have following two file on Linux Web server.

- CA = cacert.pem
- Key = key.pem

Now i want to generate certificate from it so what i need to do?

Comment: Do you want to generate a self-signed certificate, or have that certificate authority issue and sign a new certificate? What would the new certificate be used for? Web server, client certificate...?

Comment: Apache web server

Comment: Your question or at least its title is not clear. The CA is already a self signed certificate typically since it it as the top of the trust chain. If you have a CA you can create a certificate signed by this CA. Because otherwise a self signed certificate does not need a CA, you can create it just out of nothing, since it is self signed.